# Dapper .net loses connection string with Sybase 12 or 16

Tags: .net, dapper, sqlanywhere

I work with Sybase 12 and dapper.net. Everything was ok, until I made Sybase update 3817. After this update, I began to get such exception: " System.NullReferenceException:"

trace:

```
   iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.SAConnection.CalledByEntityFramework() +263
   iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.SAConnection.get_ConnectionString() +538
   Dapper.Identity..ctor(String sql, Nullable`1 commandType, IDbConnection connection, Type type, Type parametersType, Type[] otherTypes) +73
   Dapper.<QueryInternal>d__13`1.MoveNext() +545
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +381
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
   Dapper.SqlMapper.Query(IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Boolean buffered, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType) +218
   Dapper.SqlMapper.Query(IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Boolean buffered, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType) +88
```

When I looked into the connection my variablу I saw, that connection string has exception:

> 'MDbConnection.ConnectionString' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'.

I can't understand what happens in this update of sybase. All next updates of version 12 and the newest - 16 have the same trouble with dapper! But if I use ADO.Net - everything works fine!

Answer (score 1):

I decompiled the assembly, showing the following code:

```
public override string ConnectionString
{
    get
    {
        SATrace.PropertyCall("", this._objectId);
        if (this._connStr == null)
        {
            return "";
        }
        if (SAConnectionOptions.GetAdoDotNetTesting(this._connOpts))
        {
           //.....
        }
        if (SAConnectionOptions.GetPersistSecurityInfo(this._connOpts) || base.DesignMode || SAConnection.s_isHostedByVisualStudio)
        {
            return this._connStr;
        }
        if (this.CalledByEntityFramework()) //It goes wrong here
        {
            return this._connStr;
        }
        string result;
        string text2;
        string text3;
        SAConnection.RemoveKeyValuesFromString(this._connStr, SAConnectionOptions.s_passwordKeys, false, out result, out text2, out text3);
        return result;
    }
    set
    {
        ///...
    }
}
```

So I added the following to our connection string: `;Persist Security Info=True`
This will allow the code to go in the 3th `if` statement, instead of the 4 which is causing the null reference.

Answer (score 0):

That is interesting; it looks like it relates to:

```
internal Identity(string sql, CommandType? commandType, IDbConnection connection, Type type, Type parametersType, Type[] otherTypes)
    : this(sql, commandType, connection.ConnectionString, type, parametersType, otherTypes, 0)
{ }
```

So it is the simple act of querying the `.ConnectionString` that is failing. You say:

> But if I use ADO.Net - everything works fine!

I *imagine* that is because when using ADO.NET you haven't had any reason to look at the `.ConnectionString` once a connection is open. Probably the first thing to do (can you check this?) is to see whether `.ConnectionString` *does* throw an error, i.e.

```
using(var conn = new WhateverConnection(connectionString)) {
    conn.Open();
    // maybe execute a command, just for fun
    Console.WriteLine(conn.ConnectionString);
}
```

of course if might be something else in the code that is somehow making it incorrectly think it relates to Entity Framework, as per:

```
iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.SAConnection.CalledByEntityFramework() +263
```

However! Ultimately, it looks like the "problem" here is: a bug in the `SAConnection` implementation. Frankly I think this is something you need to log with sybase.